# How to expand a string macro using a counter?

Tags: counters, expansion

I try to expand a string using a counter. I will use a very simple example:

```
\def\st{}
\setcounter{i}{1}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\st\expandafter{\st{ } \the\numexpr\value{i}}
\addtocounter{i}{1}
\texttt{\st}
```

One would expect the result to be '1'. Yet, the result is '2' because the counter increased after the expansion. So, I undestand that 'st' is always "interpreted" using the final value of 'i'.
So, in an iteration of the counter 'i' one would get n n n n ... (where 'n' is the final value of 'i'). But I would like to get 1 2 ... n. How can this be done?

(I spent a lot of time trying to achieve this reault, alas, in vain!)

Comment: `\edef` rather than `\def`. But just use etoolbox macros. This would be done `\def\st{} \setcounter{tmpi}{1} \eappto\st{\the\numexpr\value{tmpi}} \addtocounter{tmpi}{1} \texttt{\st}`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. It also works with \appto. (Weird, I had already tried \appto among other things ... Maybe in the wrong way, though). BTW, why didn't you post this solution as a regular answer? I would then could upvote you.

Answer (score 4):

You need full expansion. Also, you're adding unwanted braces and spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\st#1{}
\newcounter{i}
%\renewcommand{\thei}{\arabic{i}} % it's default

\begin{document}

\count255=0
\loop
\ifnum\count255<10
  \advance\count255 1
  \stepcounter{i}
  \edef\st{\st\space\thei}
\repeat

--\st--

\end{document}
```

[image]

At the first iteration, `\st` will gobble `\space`.

A different implementation with `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\st{}
\newcounter{i}
%\renewcommand{\thei}{\arabic{i}} % it's default

\begin{document}

\count255=0
\loop
\ifnum\count255<10
  \advance\count255 1
  \stepcounter{i}
  \eappto\st{\ifdefempty\st{}{ }\thei}
\repeat

--\st--

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works too. Thanks. But it's a little more complicated than  just using '\eappto' (instead of my '\expandafter') that Manuel suggested (See comments above).

Comment: I review my comment (I can't edit it anymore). I just isolated \edef\st{\st\space\thei} from your code and put it in mine. It's even simpler than \eappto\st{}{\the\numexpr\value{i}} !