# Dynamic variable name gets overwritten

Tags: macros, expansion, csname

I'm writing a class and thus storing a bunch of data into variables.
Those variable needs to be access, and rely on a counter value.

However, when accessing the values of previously-defined variable, I'm surprised to see that **it has been overwritten**.

My MWE features a counter, `dataID`. I want data to be stored in dynamic variables declared with this pattern : `data@<counter_value>@prio`. I'm using custom macro (`getValue` and `storeValue` that resectively use `\@nameuse` and `\@namedef`).

However as you can see in the MWE, when the counter `dataID` is at 2, the variable  `data@1@prio` gets overwritten with the value stored in `data@2@prio`. How can I prevent this ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getValue}[1]{%
    \@ifundefined{#1}{%  
        \PackageError{lookup}{No #1 key defined}{}%
    }{%
        \@nameuse{\expandafter#1}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\storeValue}[2]{%
    \@namedef{#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\labelText}[1]{%
    \@bsphack
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname % for hyperrredf usage
    \def\@currentlabel{#1}{\label{#1}}%
    \@esphack
}

\newcounter{dataID}
\newcommand{\data}{%
    \refstepcounter{dataID}%
    \labelText{data\thedataID}
    data\thedataID

    \quad dataID value = \thedataID
    \expandafter\storeValue{data@\thedataID @prio}{This is \ref{data\thedataID}}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \data   % data1

    \texttt{data@1@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@1@prio} \quad\textcolor{blue}{1st Definition of \texttt{data@1@prio} !}

    ---

    \data   % data2

    \texttt{data@thedataID@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@\thedataID @prio} (because dataID=2)

    ---

    \texttt{data@1@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@1@prio} \quad\textcolor{red}{Redefinition of \texttt{data@1@prio} !}

    \texttt{data@2@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@2@prio}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output :
[image: MWE output]

Depending on the place where it's called, the value of `\getValue{data@1@prio}` is not the same.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/406279/28926 Seems related. After searching, this is about expansion of counter values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @frougon says in their nice breakdown of your code, for which he deserves the green tick, the main problem in terms of the output is that you are storing the unexpanded `\ref{data\thedataID}` so what `\getValue` returns depends on the current the value of `\thedataID`.

Rather than using `\@nameuse` and friends I recommend using the corresponding commands from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package as, at least for me, this results in more readable code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\getValue}[1]{
    \ifcsdef{#1}{\csuse{#1}}%
                {\PackageError{lookup}{No #1 key defined}{}}%
}
\newcommand{\storeValue}[2]{\csxdef{#1}{#2}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelText}[1]{\typeout{label=#1.}%
    \@bsphack
    \phantomsection % for hyperrredf usage
    \def\@currentlabel{#1}{\label{#1}}%
    \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{dataID}
\newcommand{\data}{%
    \refstepcounter{dataID}%
    \labelText{data\thedataID}
    data\thedataID

    \quad dataID value = \thedataID
    \storeValue{data@\thedataID @prio}{This is \noexpand\ref{data\thedataID}}
}

\begin{document}
    \data   % data1

    \texttt{data@1@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@1@prio} \quad\textcolor{blue}{1st Definition of \texttt{data@1@prio} !}

    ---

    \data   % data2

    \texttt{data@thedataID@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@\thedataID @prio} (because dataID=2)

    ---

    \texttt{data@1@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@1@prio} \quad\textcolor{red}{Redefinition of \texttt{data@1@prio} !}

    \texttt{data@2@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@2@prio}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You picked the question tags right: your main problem here concerns expansion. :-)

- When you do `\@nameuse{\expandafter#1}`, this is... not very useful, because:

  1. You are passing `\expandafter#1` to `\@nameuse` (with the argument substituted for `#1`), whereas you probably wanted to pass the *result* of its expansion. In this particular case, since `\@nameuse` is simply `macro:#1->\csname #1\endcsname`, its argument will be expanded anyway, due to the way `\csname` works.
  2. The `\expandafter` is not put to good use here. If you call for instance `\getValue{foo}`, when the `\getValue` control sequence token is expanded, `\getValue{foo}` will be replaced by the replacement text of `\getValue`, in which the argument `foo` will have been substituted for `#1`. In this case, this will yield:

     ```latex
     \@ifundefined{foo}{%  
         \PackageError{lookup}{No foo key defined}{}%
     }{%
         \@nameuse{\expandafter foo}%
     }%
     ```

     When TeX expands this `\@nameuse`, this will result in:

     ```latex
     \csname \expandafter foo\endcsname
     ```

     thus, when TeX gets to the expand the `\expandafter`, it will try to expand the token following `f`, i.e. the first character token `o`, which is unexpandable. So, this `\expandafter` doesn't serve any purpose.
- The other `\expandafter`:

  ```latex
  \expandafter\storeValue{data@\thedataID @prio}{This is \ref{data\thedataID}}
  ```

  has a similar problem. It will try to expand the opening brace `{` following `\storeValue`, which again is a non-active character token and therefore is unexpandable. In this case, you want to expand the two `\thedataID` tokens but not `\ref` *before* `\storeValue` is itself expanded. Therefore, I would propose something like:

  ```latex
  \begingroup
  \edef\tmp{%
    \endgroup
    \noexpand\storeValue{data@\thedataID @prio}
                        {This is \noexpand\ref{data\thedataID}}%
  }%
  \tmp
  ```

  The `\noexpand` tokens prevent expansion of the next token inside the `\edef`. Then they disappear, so that after `\tmp` is expanded in the last line of this excerpt, TeX sees:

  ```latex
  \endgroup
  \storeValue{data@1@prio}{This is \ref{data1}}%
  ```

  assuming for instance that `\thedataID` expanded to 1. The `\endgroup` closes the group where `\tmp` was defined, and what is left in the input stream is exactly what you wanted.
- Similarly, in `\labelText`, you want the argument to be recursively expanded in order to get the counter value in the replacement text of `\@currentlabel`, as opposed to the five tokens `data\thedataID` (four character tokens followed by one control sequence token). Since `\label` recursively expands its argument anyway using `\protected@write`, we can do `\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}` for consistency to expand the argument (this implies that `\protect` will work when used inside this argument in case you need it). Actually, `\def` also works here, because `\label` does `\protected@write\@auxout{}{ ... \@currentlabel ...}`, so it recursively expands both its argument and the `\@currentlabel`.

Other things:

- There is no need to wrap the `\label` call within braces (and make it look like an argument to `\def`!).
- `hyperref` should be loaded last, except in very special cases such as when `cleveref` is used (`cleveref` must be loaded after `hyperref`).
- Minor nit: you don't need `\csname ... \endcsname` to form the `\phantomsection` control sequence token (all letters p, h, a, ..., i, o, n have category code 11 in normal circumstances, i.e. are *letters* for TeX).

Note: I left your `@` as is because it works, but there is a trap, so beware. Indeed, the `@` in the replacement text of your `\data` macro has category code 11 (letter), whereas the ones in your document body have category code 12 (other). These are *not the same character tokens*. This works because in the end, they are only used inside `\csname ... \endcsname`, and *there* it doesn't matter whether they have catcode 11 or 12 (they become part of a control sequence *name*, which is just a sequence of characters in the ordinary sense, without any catcode attached). If unsure, you can always use another character, such as `.` or `-`.

All in all, I propose the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getValue}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}{%
      \PackageError{lookup}{No '#1' key defined}{}%
  }{%
      \@nameuse{#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\storeValue}[2]{%
  \@namedef{#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\labelText}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \phantomsection % for hyperrred usage
  % \def also works here (see above)
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  \label{#1}%
  \@esphack
}

\newcounter{dataID}
\newcommand{\data}{%
    \refstepcounter{dataID}%
    \labelText{data\thedataID}
    data\thedataID

    \quad dataID value = \thedataID
    \begingroup
    \edef\tmp{%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand\storeValue{data@\thedataID @prio}
                          {This is \noexpand\ref{data\thedataID}}%
    }%
    \tmp
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\data   % data1

\verb|data@1@prio|
$\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@1@prio}

---

\data   % data2

\verb|data@\thedataID@prio|
$\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@\thedataID @prio} (because dataID=2)

---

\verb|data@1@prio| $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@1@prio}

\verb|data@2@prio| $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@2@prio}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +1 for your nice breakdown of the OP

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, and +1 for your idea of using `etoolbox`. You can use the pronoun `he` for me. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation and the solution. I'll go for the `etoolbox` solution since I find it more readable indeed.

Comment: @3isenHeim Please give the tick to frougon as his solution is more comprehensive than mine and he was first to solve the actual problem that you had.

Answer (score 4):

I propose a different implementation using property lists of `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_eisenheim_values_prop
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { Nxx }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \prop_if_in:Nn { Ne } { T,F,TF,p }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \msg_expandable_error:nnn { nne }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getValue}{m}
 {
  \prop_if_in:NeTF \g_eisenheim_values_prop { #1 }
   {
    \prop_item:Ne \g_eisenheim_values_prop { #1 }
   }
   {
    \msg_expandable_error:nne { lookup } { missing } { #1 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\storeValue}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nxx \g_eisenheim_values_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\msg_new:nnn { lookup } { missing } { The~value~#1~is~missing }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelText}[1]{%
    \@bsphack
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname % for hyperref usage
    \def\@currentlabel{#1}{\label{#1}}%
    \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{dataID}

\newcommand{\data}{%
    \refstepcounter{dataID}%
    \labelText{data\thedataID}%
    data\thedataID
    \quad dataID value = \thedataID
    \storeValue{data@\thedataID @prio}{This is \noexpand\ref{data\thedataID}}
}


\begin{document}

\data   % data1

\texttt{data@1@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@1@prio}

---

\data   % data2

\texttt{data@thedataID@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@\thedataID @prio} (because dataID=2)

---

\texttt{data@1@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@1@prio} 

\texttt{data@2@prio} $\rightarrow$ \getValue{data@2@prio}

\getValue{x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage is that `\getValue` is fully expandable.

Comment: +1 for showing me `\mes_new:nnn` but do you really want to advocate the use of `\csname phantomsection\endcsname`? Also, is there a more elegant eplc3 replacement for `\@bsphack...\@esphack`?

Comment: @Andrew That's a known trick. Possibly, in a not so far future, the LaTeX kernel can provide a way to avoid it. As far as `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` is concerned, there's nothing better ATM.